# MemoryCache - how to change its physical memory limit?

Tags: c#, caching

I have this:

```
var crumbsCache = new MemoryCache("breadCrumbsNames", new NameValueCollection { { "PhysicalMemoryLimit", "200" } });
```

And when I check this object at runtime, it has memorylimit set to 98. Always. How can I incerase this limit?

Answer (score 1):

Your NameValueCollection item is wrong, change the **PhysicalMemoryLimit** to **physicalMemoryLimitPercentage** and the *physicalMemoryLimitPercentage* value **cannot be greater than** '**100'.**